# Django prefetch_related() in ListView class based view

Tags: django, prefetch, csb

I have a simple blog with 2 models: one for Post and one for Comment, like so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # content = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True, config_name='claudiu_cfg')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=350)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.author
```

I want to display all posts (paginated) and how many comments each have.
My views.py:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
```

Just like this i was getting all posts, but now i want to access the Comment table with as little selects as possible.
I know one way to do this is define a queryset and did it like this:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
    queryset = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related()
```

However  that does not access the Comment data.

Then i tried to overrite the `get_queryset()` function hopping to get the desired result. Still no success.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    posts = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('pk__comment').all()
    comments = Comment.objects.all().prefetch_related('post')

    print(dir(posts))
    print('---------------------')
    print(posts._prefetch_done)

return posts.order_by('-date_posted')
```

That still doesnt work and i cant understand where to go from here.
I did read the documentation, but that still didnt help me.

Please help, as i have nobody to ask for help when it comes to django.

It looks like the solution was closer than i expected, based on responses from 
@dirkgroten i managed to fix my issue like so:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
    queryset = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('comment_set').all()
```

To display the number of comments in my template, in a for loop i added:

```
{{ post.comment_set.all|length }}
```

Thank you, without your help it would have taken me atleast a few more hours if not days.

Comment: What do you mean with does not access. The `.prefetch_related` makes *no* JOIN. It is basically a "promise" that it will join programmatically by making one extra query (not one per element).

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What do you do that shows it doesn't work? How are you displaying the comments or the number of comments? (note: you should `prefetch_related('comment')` not `'pk__comment'`).

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity without overriting the get_queryset(), i get no errors whatsoever, but in that situation I may need to overrite the get() func to display a custom context that includes number of comments for post and i dont know how to access the coments since queryset returns a <QuerySet> object where i can only see the posts. eg: 'posts': <QuerySet [<Post: 29>, <Post: Banana>. For @dirkgroten leaving just comment throws this exception: Exception Value: 
Cannot find 'comment' on Post object, 'comment' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: sorry, `prefetch_related('comment_set')` since you didn't define a `related_name`. But again, when you view the `posts` queryset, as Willem said, it will show you the list of posts. If you then on each post access `post.comment_set.all()` it will do the second query to fetch all the comments for all the posts in the queryset. (only **one** query due to prefetch). In your template, you could access `{{ post.comment_set.all|length }}` or `{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}`

Comment: oh wow, about 6h ago did the "comment_set" in the prefetch_related() however i was unaware how to access the values. From my understanding it creates a new key for each post and then associate the comments to that key, am I right or the logic behind is different?